# How do you use NFC to transfer files without external storage?

Tags: android, nfc, android-external-storage

I'm currently developing an application for a Nexus S phone that will be storing data to permanent storage and will transfer that data when two phones are in close proximity. This seems like the job for NFC and I've been reading into it on the Android developers training page.

On the following page...

http://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/send-files.html

The tutorial states as a second requirement for Android Beam file transfer...

> Files you want to transfer must reside in external storage.

The issue is the Nexus S does not have external storage (no SD card), but I have a good idea that file transfer with NFC is an option for the Nexus S. How should I interpret this requirement? How can I use the Nexus S's internal storage to keep and share files between phones?

Comment: Did you follow the [Using the External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is the Nexus S does not have external storage

Yes, it does.

> no SD card

This has little to do with external storage nowadays. SD cards have not been used for a device's primary external storage in the past couple of years, except on a smattering of devices.

> I have a good idea that file transfer with NFC is an option for the Nexus S

Yes.

> How should I interpret this requirement?

Put the file on external storage.

Comment: Thanks about clearing up the misconception. 


I found an extra comment that helped clear up my misconceptions of external storage.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11212626/1819282

Comment: @JamesHaynes: FWIW, ideally, you could use something like `FileProvider` to beam a file from internal storage. I was surprised to see that they explicitly say that is not supported.