# Android how much to store in internal storage

Tags: android

This may be an already answered question, but I guess I'm still a bit confused. I've read most of the questions related to storage, I understand the pros and cons of each solution, I want to use the internal storage, but I still feel stuck because of the space constraints. 
I've got a working app that can save up to 200 images which can be over 100k each(so more or less 20MB of data). The app will also be restricted to the new generation of phones(Samsung Galaxy S3,4 , Iphone 5s) because of camera requirements.

I'd like to save the images in the internal storage because I don't want the users messing about with them and I'm guessing that it should be fine, but I know there can be quite restrictive limits to the allowed memory. Is 20MB too much? where can I find the amount of internal app-allocated memory?

here I found that the memory is no longer physically distinct(
[external-internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212377/external-internal-storage)) which raises the question how is it allocated?

A little insight would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there can be quite restrictive limits to the allowed memory

Not since Android 3.0, for most devices. Android 3.0+ has internal and external storage sharing one partition by default, so if a device is advertised as having 8GB of space, that is available to both internal and external storage. You will find the occasional oddball device that has separate internal and external storage, but they are the exception, not the rule, for Android 3.0+.

Comment: Thanks Commons, I didn't know that! Helps a lot!